# How to access query parameters like $orderBy in controller actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am just reading the Microsoft REST API Guidlines (https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/master/Guidelines.md) and there are query parameters described beginning with a dollar sign, e.g. `$orderBy`.

> ### 9.6 Sorting collections
>
> The results of a collection query MAY be sorted based on property
>   values. The property is determined by the value of the $orderBy query
>   parameter.

Now if I try to define a method parameter like `$orderBy` in an action method then it is not syntactically correct (`$orderBy` is not a valid identifier).

```
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    // this is syntactically not correct
    public IActionResult Collection(...., string $orderBy = null)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

How can I access a query parameter beginning with a dollar sign in an action method of ASP.NET Core ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `FromQuery` and set name `[FromQuery(Name = "$orderBy")]string orderBy`:

```
public class ExampleController : Controller
{        
    public IActionResult Collection(...., [FromQuery(Name = "$orderBy")]string orderBy = null)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```